# Create several new variables using a vector of names and a vector for computation within dplyr::mutate

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I'd like to create several new columns. They should take their names from one vector and they should be computed by taking one column in the data and dividing it by another.

```r
mytib <- tibble(id = 1:2, value1 = c(4,6), value2 = c(42, 5), total = c(2,2))
myvalues <- c("value1", "value2")
mynames  <- c("value1_percent", "value2_percent")

mytib %>%
     mutate({{ mynames }} := {{ myvalues }}/total)
```

Here, I get the error message, which makes me think that the curly-curly operator is misplaced

> Error in local_error_context(dots = dots, .index = i, mask = mask) : promise already under evaluation: recursive default argument reference or earlier problems?

I'd like to calculate the percentage columns programmatically (since I have many such columns in my data).

The desired output should be equivalent to this:

```
mytib %>%
    mutate( "value1_percent" = value1/total, "value2_percent" = value2/total)
```

which gives

```
# A tibble: 2 × 6
     id value1 value2 total value1_percent value2_percent
  <int>  <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl>          <dbl>          <dbl>
1     1      4     42     2              2           21  
2     2      6      5     2              3            2.5
```

Comment: Hi, if your question has been solved, please select one of the answers you prefer as accepted by clicking the check mark next to it. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You could use `across` and construct the new names in its `.names` argument:

```
library(dplyr)

mytib %>%
    mutate(across(starts_with('value'),
                  ~ .x / total,
                  .names = "{.col}_percent"
                  ))
```

Answer (score 2):

I prefer `mutate(across(...))` in this case. To make your idea work, try `reduce2()` from `purrr`.

```r
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

reduce2(mynames, myvalues,
        ~ mutate(..1, !!..2 := !!sym(..3)/total), .init = mytib)

# # A tibble: 2 x 6
#      id value1 value2 total value1_percent value2_percent
#   <int>  <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl>          <dbl>          <dbl>
# 1     1      4     42     2              2           21  
# 2     2      6      5     2              3            2.5
```

The above code is actually a shortcut of:

```r
mytib %>%
  mutate(!!mynames[1] := !!sym(myvalues[1])/total,
         !!mynames[2] := !!sym(myvalues[2])/total)
```

Comment: upvote for the ninja-like purrr construct :-)